# How to create a table, import joined columns, and insert the data in to the new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have used a JOIN to put together a query that uses columns from multiple tables.  I want to use that query to insert the appropriate data in a new table.

I see the columns I want and I know how to create a new table (before the join statements).  I have seen many examples how to create the table and then the JOIN the columns.  How do I get all 160k records in to that table?

OK here is the query I have so far....

-- Select appropriate columns

```
SELECT AP.[ApprovedID], AP.[TermID], AP.[SchoolID], AP.[CipCode]
   , CX.[JobCode],  DE.[DOECode], AP.[SA_Level], AP.[CreditHours]
   , AP.[IsActive], AP.[NONVOCED], AP.[CreateDate], AP.[CreatedBy]
   , AP.[LastUpdateDate], AP.[LastUpdatedBy], AP.[Designator], AP.[ChangeFlag]
```

-- Put it into a new table

```
INTO [INTERS_2004].[inters].[inters_tblApprovedProgramsTest]
```

-- Put in the joins here

```
FROM [INTERS_2004].[inters].[inters_tblApprovedPrograms] AP
JOIN [INTERS_2004].[inters].[inters_tblCIPDOECrosswalk] CX
   ON AP.[CipCode] = CX.[JobCode] 
JOIN [INTERS_2004].[inters].[inters_tblDOECode] DE
   ON CX.[DOECode] = DE.[DOECode]

ORDER BY AP.[ApprovedID]
```

....and at that point my knowledge fizzles in to the air...

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us what you have so far?

Comment: What happens when you execute that query?  It looks okay to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the table name you want to use does not already exist, use the [`SELECT ... INTO ...` syntax](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/04/30/sql-server-ctas-create-table-as-select-what-is-ctas/):

```
SELECT ...
  INTO new_table
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t2.col = t1.col 
 WHERE ...
```

Comment: -- Select appropriate columns

SELECT AP.[ApprovedID], AP.[TermID], AP.[SchoolID], AP.[CipCode], CX.[JobCode], DE.[DOECode], AP.[SA_Level], AP.[CreditHours], AP.[IsActive], AP.[NONVOCED], AP.[CreateDate], AP.[CreatedBy], AP.[LastUpdateDate], AP.[LastUpdatedBy], AP.[Designator], AP.[ChangeFlag]

-- Put it into a new table
INTO [INTERS_2004].[inters].[inters_tblApprovedProgramsTest]

-- Put in the joins here